Quantum process tomography of a non-CPTP map
Let's say I have a theoretical/ computational process that inverts the outputs of a quantum channel and returns noise-free input density matrices. I perform quantum process tomography on my process and obtain a $\chi$ matrix that has negative eigenvalues (meaning that the process is not CPTP) but $\chi$ is Hermitian and has trace $1$.
How do I interpret this $\chi$ matrix then? I think that maybe it means that the inverse map is an HPTP map, but I am not sure because I don't know much about HPTP maps. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

I'd say you interpret it the same way you interpret state estimates obtained from linear state tomography (which may very well have negative eigenvalues).
It's an estimate, whose elements you know are with high probability within a given distance from the true state.
If you do linear state tomography of a pure state from some informationally complete POVM (or mutually unbiased basis if you prefer) you might obtain an estmiate $\hat\rho$ that's not a proper state. But that doesn't really matter, because you can simply understand $\hat\rho$ as a way to estimate observables of $\rho$, and when you do that small negative eigenavalues aren't an issue. If you want to estimate other things, eg the entropy, then using this method won't work well, and this tells you that you shouldn't do linear state tomography to estimate those kinds of parameters. Because of linear state tomography does is really define unbiased estimators for the coefficients of the state in a given operatorial basis.
Same goes for process tomography, which essentially amounts to doing state tomography of the Choi of the map. You can interpret "non-physical" results in the estimate as statistical errors in the estimate of how some state should evolve in some other state.
I don't think the map being CPTP or not matters in this: I'd guess even doing (linear) process tomography of a CPTP you can obtain non-physical results as estimates.
Unless you're doing a different kind of tomographic approach, eg maximum likelihood approaches? Then the situation might change considerably.

But since it represents the inverse of a quantum channel, it has to be non-CPTP, so that is expected. I was actually wondering if we can say that it is an HPTP map and then possibly represent it as a linear combination of CPTP maps as they say in this paper https://arxiv.org/abs/2012.10959 Any thoughts on that?

@rand1 oh, so you're asking whether/why the inverse of a CPTP is Hermitian-preserving? I'd say yes: because CPTPs are Hermitian-preserving, they send Hermitians into Hermitians, and also don't send non-Hermitians to Hermitians. Thus their inverse has to also preserve Hermitianity (btw, you'll find plenty of discussions on channels and related topics on https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/)
